# How to Show/Hide Busy Indicator SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I need to show busy indicator during AJAX call. So I have used `<BusyIndicator text="Please wait ..."/>`. How to Show/Hide this indicator in controller?. Now its always showing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two BusyIndicators in UI5.
`sap.m.BusyIndicator` is used to create a customized busy indicator. In this case, you should destroy the object reference after it's not necessary anymore (of course, you have to maintain a reference object for the BusyIndicator). This type should be used if you want to indicate that only a specific part of the UI is loading. (For these situations, you can use the control's `setBusy()` function)

For a global busy indicator, `sap.ui.core.BusyIndicator` can be used. It cannot be customized; it's just a loading icon. You can display it using the `sap.ui.core.BusyIndicator.show();` and hide it using the `sap.ui.core.BusyIndicator.hide();` function.

If you are using `Page`s in your application, you can set the busy status of the page itself; you can bind this property to a Model and you can control the indicator by setting the model property.

You can find more details [here](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/0dd211065c714c0d8a35cecb5fea8557.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I have used `BusyDialog` as fragment & it worked perfectly !!  I have set `oDialog.open()` within `beforeSend()` of jquery ajax. Initially it took 2 sec to display but after setting `async : true`, dialog showed immediately !!